# Angular: How to have dynamic start of carousel with @ngu/carousel library

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, carousel, ngu-carousel

I have a requirement to start a carousel to start with a dynamic index, not from 0. Do we have any npm package, support for Angular 4 or above .

@ngu/carousel is already use, myCarousel.moveTo() doesn't seem to work for this senario

Comment: any feedback on the answer to your question below?

Answer (score 1):

You can just randomize your primary Array (the array with images), that way each new view of the page will see a different sequence in your carousel

relevant **HTML**:

```
<ngu-carousel #myCarousel [inputs]="carouselConfig" [dataSource]="carouselItems">
    <div *nguCarouselDef="let item;" class="item">
        <div class="tile">{{item}}</div>
    </div>
    <button NguCarouselNext class="rightRs">></button>
    <button NguCarouselPrev class="leftRs"><</button>
    <ul class="myPoint" NguCarouselPoint>
        <li *ngFor="let j of myCarousel.pointNumbers; let j = index" [class.active]="j==myCarousel.activePoint" (click)="myCarousel.moveTo(j)"></li>
    </ul>
</ngu-carousel>
```

relevant **TS**:

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit, ViewChild, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
import { NguCarousel, NguCarouselConfig } from '@ngu/carousel';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-simple',
  templateUrl: './simple.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./simple.component.css']
})
export class SimpleComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  name = 'Angular';
  slideNo = 0;
  withAnim = true;
  resetAnim = true;

  @ViewChild('myCarousel') myCarousel: NguCarousel;
  carouselConfig: NguCarouselConfig = {
    grid: { xs: 1, sm: 1, md: 1, lg: 1, all: 0 },
    load: 3,
    interval: { timing: 4000, initialDelay: 1000 },
    loop: true,
    touch: true,
    velocity: 0.2
  }
  carouselItems: any[];

  constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {
    let myArray: any[] = ['item 1', 'item 2', 'item 3'];
    myArray = this.shuffleArray(myArray);
    this.carouselItems = myArray;
  }

  shuffleArray(array) {
    for (let i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
      const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
      [array[i], array[j]] = [array[j], array[i]];
    }
    return array;
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.cdr.detectChanges();
  }

  reset() {
    this.myCarousel.reset(!this.resetAnim);
  }

  moveTo(slide) {
    this.myCarousel.moveTo(slide, !this.withAnim);
  }
}
```

check a [working stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngu-carousel-demo-bbmnph?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Answer (score 0):

Moving `myCarousel.moveTo()` to  within `ngAfterViewInit(){}` rather than `ngOnInit(){}` worked for me.

Responding to old thread as I overcame same problem in different way to previous answer.